# Break or Lag in Audio from PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio, itunes, vlc-media-player

I'm experiencing Audio breaks in my PC when played any Song in VLC Media Player or iTunes. But Windows Media Player works fine. What is the reason?

Note - I have tried re-installing all my Audio drivers; I had even checked my Speakers with my phone - No Issues with my speakers too. - Creative SBS A120 - 2.1 Speakers

Comment: What file type? Play the file with Task Manager and watch the performance to ensure it's not maxing out. What drivers are you using, the official ones of the MS ones?

Comment: Mkv video file or MP3 Audio file ; Realtek Audio Driver